# Is there any option for get enabled chrome extension by using javascript

Tags: angular

I want to get all the chrome extension list by using java script for my project is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way, the only option I could think of is that you write your own Chrome extension and pass that info to your desired destination.

If you want to follow that route: you can use [`chrome.management.getAll`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-getAll) to obtain a list of the installed extensions and apps.